# Eliminating WordPress Error "Hello world! Please change me in Site Preferences -> This Category/Section -> Lower Description Bar"

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, wordpress-theming

I inherited some unfinished website from another developer on WordPress 4.2.2 running the Wise Guys theme. On other pages, the Lower Description Bar shows great quotes from people, but on a specific page (the gallery page) it shows these words... `Hello world! Please change me in Site Preferences -> This Category/Section -> Lower Description Bar`. Obviously it looks ugly.

I am not a great WordPress user myself,  I prefer Joomla, but my client is needing his site to work right in WordPress.

I've got a few questions in this regard:

1) How do I tell the Category/Section of the specific page so that I can follow that suggested path above? I don't seem to find a reasonable route; after all there's only one category that doesn't seems to feature anywhere on the pages.

2) When I login to the backend and follow that path (Site Preferences -> etc...) there's little to do or change. Where in the file system could I do a manual edit, if need be? I'd still want to keep the quotes showing on the other pages, even on this particular page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check which plugins are activated.  The quotes sounds like "Hello Dolly" is activated.  You can deactivate it, since it is a default plugin included with the WordPress download.

As for manual edits, all of your changes should take place in your theme, keep in mind that any changes to a third party theme will be overwritten with any updates. So, you should rename the theme to a custom name. Themes are locate in the themes folder "/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-content/themes".

Comment: Thanks deronimo but Hello Dolly is actually deactivated